# Read flat file in a SSIS package with optional additional columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In a SSIS package, I've got a flat file that may have seven columns or two additional columns at the end making nine columns.

Example file1:

```
StoreId,Overall Service Score,FindingHelp,Friendly,PaySpeed,GoodTarget,ExceptionalTarget
0286,0.84,0.79,0.90,0.84,0.81,0.81
0014,0.76,0.75,0.77,0.77,0.84,0.99
```

Example file2:

```
StoreId,Overall Service Score,FindingHelp,Friendly,PaySpeed,GoodTarget,ExceptionalTarget,PPU_OverallScore,PPU_Target
0286,0.84,0.79,0.90,0.84,0.81,0.81,0.8,0.6
0014,0.76,0.75,0.77,0.77,0.84,0.99,0.9,1
```

Can both versions of these files be handled within a SSIS package and if so, how?

I've created a Data Flow like so and this works for example file2. However, when trying with file1, I get the following error:

```
[Flat File Source [19]] Error: An error occurred while skipping data rows.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Flat File Source returned error code 0xC0202091.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

[image]

My conditional flow:

[image]

Update: with additional screenshot:

[image]

Comment: They *can* be but not by the same data flow task. SSIS expects well defined files, and a file that has a variable number of columns is *not* well defined. You'll need to ensure you have 2 separate sources, and probably 2 separate data flow tasks and then ensure the correct one is used. You'll also need to ensure that the data sources and data flows are set to delay their validation so that they are validated when they are referenced, rather than when the package starts to execute(which would likely cause an error due to one the file not meeting expectations).

Comment: Alternatively you could have a process add the "missing" columns to the file that doesn't have them, or remove them from the one that does, and then have a single process that consumes them, but that is likely more work than just implementing conditional flows to use the correct data flow task for the file you are consuming. Ideally you should be ensuring that what ever process is supplying the data is doing so in a consistent format.

Comment: @larnu The example file2 is new and so the idea of being able to handle two different formats is so there's a fall back option is file2 doesn't work. I guess an alternative approach could be to create a separate identical SSIS package which handles the different file format?

Comment: If you're determined to use SSIS for variant CSV files (those where each file can be a different subset of the full schema) you'll need to look into Programmatic Packages. Ref: [Creating a Package Programmatically](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/creating-a-package-programmatically). These can be created from an SSIS Script Task that parses the header row of input files to create a dynamic package that maps the current input columns to the columns available in the destination table and executes it in-memory. They aren't trivial.

Comment: Please add to your question one more screen shot. Double click on the green line between **Flat Fie Source** and **Conditional Split**. It will bring up **Data Flow Path Editor**. Select **Metadata**, and share its screen  shot.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Added to the OP. The flat file connection manager used in the failing flat file source is configured with the two additional columns. I take it that its failing because the two columns aren't in file1.

Comment: For this type of task I usually build a script source component with the max. number of output columns and handle the evaluation of the number of provided columns within this component... works pretty well so far :)

Comment: I'd go full c#. Load into data table and process the columns available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily resolve the issue by modifying the expressions for the Conditional Split task, and adding `ISNULL()` function and an immediate if conditional expression to handle NULLs.

Along the following:

```
ISNULL(PPU_Target) ? "" : PPU_Target 
ISNULL(PPU_OverallScore) ? "" : PPU_OverallScore
```